# Angular: CSS not properly loading after redirect to home component

Tags: node.js, angular

CSS is not properly loading after redirect to home component in Angular.

I define my routes as

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'aboutus', component: AboutusComponent },
  { path: 'contactus', component: ContactusComponent },
  { path: 'boards', component: BoardsComponent },
  { path: 'board', component: BoardComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '*', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: '', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

I tried different options but not succeeded, like

```
<a role="button" routerLink="../home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>

or 

 redirectToHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

home page like this before redirecting to another component

[image: when redirect to home component]

What's the issue?

Comment: Image in the question, showing the home component after redirecting to home component.

Comment: also paste the style before redirection

Comment: Have you tried removing the ```/``` in your url?

Comment: If there is "ViewEncapsulation.NONE" in "HomeComponent", you will have this problem, check it, and eliminate it.